# Unable to port FFmpeg C library into android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

**What I exactly want to-do**: Access the **ffmpeg.c** file to modify the **int main(int argc, char **argv)** function to **JNI** and passing the command of ffmpeg as string.

I have tried to port ffmpeg C library to android(ARM processor). I followed following different ways to do this.

1st Try: using official ffmpeg installation documentation. Steps as follows

a) git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg

b) Read the INSTALL file.

c) Download x264 library and build by using **build_x264.sh** which build successfully.

```
    NDK=/home/nav/Work/android/ndk
    PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt
    PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
    PREFIX=/home/nav/28ffmpeg/android-ffmpeg                
    ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-static --enable-pic --disable-asm --disable-cli --host=arm-linux --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=$PLATFORM
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo ldconfig
```

d) Then I download **ffmpeg library** from (http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2) build it by using **build_android.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=/home/nav/Work/android/ndk
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86
PREFIX=/home/nav/28ffmpeg/android-ffmpeg

function build_one
                {
                ./configure --target-os=linux --prefix=$PREFIX \
                --enable-cross-compile \
                --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
                --disable-asm \
                --arch=arm \
                --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
                --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
                --disable-stripping \
                --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
                --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
                --enable-nonfree \
                --enable-version3 \
                --disable-everything \
                --enable-gpl \
                --disable-doc \
                --enable-avresample \
                --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
                --enable-muxer=rtsp \
                --disable-ffplay \
                --disable-ffserver \
                --enable-ffmpeg \
                --disable-ffprobe \
                --enable-libx264 \
                --enable-encoder=libx264 \
                --enable-decoder=h264 \
                --enable-protocol=rtp \
                --enable-hwaccels \
                --enable-zlib \
                --disable-devices \
                --disable-avdevice \
--extra-cflags="-I/home/android-ffmpeg/include -fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a" \
                --extra-ldflags="-L/home/android-ffmpeg/lib"
                make -j4 install

$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavfilter/libavfilter.a libavresample/libavresample.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog -lx264 --warn-once --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
                }

                build_one
```

e) Initially it works perfectly. But after that **error** comes:

```
libavformat/libavformat.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
libavutil/libavutil.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
build_android.sh: 48: build_one: not found
```

**Result:** **libffmpeg.so** not found.

2nd Try: Then I follow steps in http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22605641/ffmpeg_android/main.html-> Builds

a) I downloaded Pre-Build **libffmpeg.so** from above link.

b) Add **libffmpeg.so** to **libs/armeabi/** .

c) Make **Android.mk**

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libffmpeg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := main
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-test.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

d) Then I do all ndk set up and all.Copy **ffmpeg.c** from library to **ffmpeg-test.c** by changing its **int main** function to my **JNI** functin and include all necessary include files.

**Error:**

**Console:**

```
  /home/nav/Work/android/ndk/ndk-build all 
Prebuilt       : libffmpeg.so <= jni/
Install        : libffmpeg.so => libs/armeabi/libffmpeg.so
Compile thumb  : main <= ffmpeg-test.c
jni/ffmpeg-test.c: In function 'print_report':
jni/ffmpeg-test.c:1139:94: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'log2' [enabled by default]
SharedLibrary  : libmain.so
/home/nav/Work/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/ffmpeg-test.o: in function check_keyboard_interaction:jni/ffmpeg-test.c:2496: error: undefined reference to 'qp_hist'
```

and many other undefined references.

Comment: I think this is the hardest thing: to get FFMPEG works, i combined several tutorials and used Android NDK v6, cause each higher NDK version gives me different errors. I can give you one adwise and i hope it will save you some time: when you will try to run `main` method of FFMPEG tool like from command line, made it in different process, cause  when it finish working or any error occures native code will execute `exit(0)` and will kill whole your process, including your Android app.GL!

Comment: `undefined reference`  problem solved by adding **LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true** this line to **Android.mk**....But now error comes : **Could not load library "libffmpeg.so" needed for "libmain.so"** .Means libmain.so is Unable to find libffmpeg.so pre-built library.....But both are forming at **libs/armeabi/** ......

Comment: I am not able to access the function inside the .so file as i am getting `undefined reference` error ....plz help

Comment: @Evos have you successfully complied ffmpeg on windows for android?see the link and if you know anything post there i will give you upvote..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141348/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-1-2-1-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r8e

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

look at this project on git for clues on making changes to 'ffmpeg.c.main()'
I believe that the build for this project will work fine on release of NDK mentioned in the readme.

Note:

you should spend some time with all the doc files in the NDK distro so that u understand how the make works.

The exit condition of the 'main()'  function usually needs to be altered slightly for android JNI .

Comment: I tried to comile above project but i got some errors and failed to form .so file. And I have edited my main() function of ffmpeg.c but error coming is **libffmpeg.so** is not found by **libmain.so**

Comment: when I am including prebuilt shared library **libffmpeg.so** to my project, it gets successfully included in compile time but is not able to load library **libmylib.so** which is being used for **libmain.so**

Plzz Help....

Comment: @Robert Rowntree can you please tell me steps?i have also updated related question on SO see the link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141348/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-1-2-1-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r8e

Comment: @Robert Rowntree i have given you +1...i hope gurdianProject will work for me....please provide me some steps so that i can build the library and also post your answer on my above link so that i can give you upvote.:)

Comment: could not find the link.  @pratik - if u are on windows, working with NDK and ffmpeg.main(), IMO consider a VM. In the long run, i think u may get better result than using cygwin and all the issues that drags in to NDK builds of ffmpeg.

Comment: @Robert Rowntree ohh sry i have deleted it...i have found this https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg is it working?

Comment: @ Robert Rowntree i want to solve this anyhow..if i find the solution i will sure post it on SO...lots of developers r facing same prob...it's creepy shit....frustrating... not even a single tutorial found....!

Comment: r u on windows? lst time i built guardian it worked according to the readme. Im on linux.

Comment: @RobertRowntree - The steps are mentioned in my question above. Need help

Answer (score 0):

To fix the multiple definitions add:

```
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar -dv libavcodec.a log2_tab.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar -dv libavutil.a log2_tab.o
```

But you might also want to add this config option:

```
--disable-symver
```

This way I managed to compile the HEAD version of ffmpeg with ndk v8 but using the LGPL license which contains lots less features.

Comment: have you successfully complied ffmpeg on windows for android?see the link and if you know anything post there i will give you upvote..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141348/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-1-2-1-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r8e

Answer (score 0):

To fix the multiple defination problem you need to delete the duplicate *.o so that clashes dont happen. I was able to achieve the same using the following command.

rm /libavcodec/log2_tab.o

rm /ffmpeg-3.0.1/libavcodec/reverse.o