# Why error happened when build ffmpeg by ndk-build?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have try build the `ffmpeg` for Android in Windows 7 , but it error when `ndk-build`.

And the error log is like the following :

```
Wun@Wun-PC ~/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg
$ ndk-build
SharedLibrary  : libffmpeg.so
C:/cygwin/home/Wun/ffmpeg/obj/local/armeabi/libavcodec.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `ff_log2_tab'
C:/cygwin/home/Wun/ffmpeg/obj/local/armeabi/libavformat.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
C:/cygwin/home/Wun/ffmpeg/obj/local/armeabi/libavutil.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `ff_log2_tab'
C:/cygwin/home/Wun/ffmpeg/obj/local/armeabi/libavformat.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/Wun/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:378: recipe for target '/home/Wun/ffmpeg/obj/local/armeabi/libffmpeg.so' failed
make: *** [/home/Wun/ffmpeg/obj/local/armeabi/libffmpeg.so] Error 1
```

I have already remove the 
`OBJS-$(CONFIG_SHARED)                  += log2_tab.o` 
in the `Makefile` of `libavformat` and `libavcodec`.

But the problem still happened...

Should I delete the `libavcodec.a , libavformat.a , libavutil.a and libswscale.a` , and rebuild again??

Does somebody know how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been [reported](http://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2013-October/149144.html) more than once in cross-compilation scenarios.

It's a [configuration problem](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2012-June/084871.html). For gcc, you should run

```
./configure … --extra-cflags="-DHAVE_ISNAN -DHAVE_ISINF"
```

<s>You can add this to **Android.mk**, too:</s>

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += "-DHAVE_ISNAN -DHAVE_ISINF"
```

Since you don't run `./configure` You can edit the `config.h` file and set these two:

```
#define HAVE_ISNAN=1
#define HAVE_ISINF=1
```

Comment: I add the `LOCAL_CFLAGS += "-DHAVE_ISNAN -DHAVE-ISINF"` at each Android.mk. The error does not solve and it show `config.h:131:0: warning: "HAVE_ISNAN" redefined [enabled by default]
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition`.

Comment: I have reference the link , but I didn't know how to add `--extra-cflags="-DHAVE_ISNAN -DHAVE-ISINF"` for GCC ?

Comment: OK, let's try only LOCAL_CFLAGS += "-DHAVE-ISINF"`. If this does not solve the problems, please publish your `config.h` file.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is at `HAVE_ISNAN and DHAVE-ISINF`. I didn't see any parameter about `HAVE_ISNAN and DHAVE-ISINF` in the error log ...

Comment: Alex , I have add the link of my `config.h`

Comment: My bad, _that's what happens when you edit this stuff on a telephone_. Sure, it is -DHAVE_ISINF. You can simply edit your `config.h` to set both `HAVE_ISNAN=1` and `HAVE_ISINF=1`

Comment: I found the problem , I only remove the "static" in `libm.h`. It should remove the all static method in `libm.h`. And it work fine.

Comment: But I have the new problem...I have edit in the above.

Comment: I am afraid you are not using the power of StackExchange this way. Please open a new question about `ff_log2_tab` if the following solution does not help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15155150/192373